Performing a one-way repeated measures MANOVA in R
I am trying to perform a one-way repeated measures MANOVA in R. My dataset has 4 dependent numeric variables, and a factor of the type of measure that was used (each participant was measured twice, once with each measure).
I have tried using car::Anova()/car::Manova(), manova(), rstatix::anova_test() and MANOVA.RM::multRM(), however each one of them had its own problem. MANOVA.RM::multRM() and car::Anova() seemed to work in modeling and providing the omnibus test results, however I wasn't able to find a way to get effect sizes from them or performing post-hoc tests.
Would love to get help or directions on how to properly perform such an analysis.

Hi, welcome to SO, you should include a minimal reproducible example dataset so we can better understand what you need
